# Extract triple backtick fenced code block ``` excerpts from markdown file

Tags: sed

I have a pandoc markdown file which has a lot of code. I want to extract all the code bits from file preferably using `sed`. The syntax of code in pandoc is three or more `` ` signs to start and finish the code segment.

````
```
Code is here
```
````

I can extract one line but I have no way of extracting *between markers*.

Comment: Keep your sanity and use a parser ;-)

Answer (score 9):

````
sed -n '/^```/,/^```/ p' < input.file
````

Will print all lines between ``` but including the ``` lines too.  To get rid of that:

````
sed -n '/^```/,/^```/ p' < input.file | sed '/^```/ d'
````

You can find an explanation of how to use line ranges by pattern, and the 'p' and 'd' commands starting here:

http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-29

Answer (score 5):

**NOTE:** *I'm the primary developer & maintainer of rundoc.*

---

For anyone looking for a general purpose tool for these kinds of things:

[Rundoc](https://gitlab.com/nul.one/rundoc) is a general purpose tool for running or extracting fenced code blocks from markdown files. You can install it through pip for python3: `pip3 install rundoc`.

To extract code blocks:

```
rundoc list-blocks your_file.md -t#bash#perl#python
```

will extract code blocks with `bash`, `perl` or `python` highlighting tag. Unfortunately code blocks without highlighting tags are always ignored.

You can also run markdown file as a script with

```
rundoc run your_file.md -t#bash#perl#python
```

This will execute all code blocks with matching highlighting tag and use highlighting tag to find proper interpreter.

**NOTE:** To get pure code without JSON or headers, use `jq` tool:

```
rundoc list-blocks your_file.md | jq -r "(.code_blocks[] | {code}).code"
```

Comment: The output of code extraction is json. If you also add `--pretty` to the command above, you will have it printed in terminal as user readable code.

Comment: I added it. It should be more prominent, since it's a new tool to the opensource community, IMO. If it were Linus talking about Git/Linux that could be down further 8-).

Answer (score 3):

You can use pandoc itself to extract the code from all code blocks. (These instructions are for pandoc version >= 2.0. No other software is needed; pandoc includes a lua interpreter.).

Create a file `extractcode.lua` with contents:

```
function CodeBlock(el)
    print(el.text)
end
```

Now run pandoc as follows, where `myfile.md` is your markdown file:

```
pandoc --lua-filter extractcode.lua myfile.md -o /dev/null
```

This will print the contents of all the code blocks. Note that this will include *all* code blocks in `myfile.md`, including indented code blocks.  Unlike the sed solutions proposed in the other answers, it will also include code blocks that occur in indented contexts like list items or blockquotes:

`````
1.  ```lua
    a = 5
    ````

> ```
> my code
> ```
`````

And it will not get confused by things like this, where the backticks are part of the code block and not delimiters:

`````
````
```
code example with three backticks as part of the code block
```
````
`````

Comment: Worked for me!!

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `perl`:

```
perl -0777e '$_=<>;print $1 while /^`{3,}\s*\n(.*?)^`{3,}\s*\n/msg' your_file
```

**Explanation**

- The `0777` part sets the input record separator (`$/`) to slurp the whole file
- The regex looks for a line starting with 3 or more backticks then matches and captures as few lines as possible (guaranteed by the lazy quantifier `*?`) followed by a line starting with 3 or more ticks.
- The regex modifier `m` ensures that `^` would match beginning of lines not just the start of the file. The modifier `s` makes sure that `.` will match a newline character so that `.*?` can match several lines. Finally `g` makes sure that the regex will be applied iteratively to the file contents so that all matches are found.